# Capture a list of words that doesn't contain an Oxford comma

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x

I am trying to isolate parts of an essay that include a list of three or more words but no Oxford comma. The regular expression I came up with is:

```
([a-z]+)(,\s*[a-z]+)(\s*or|and+)(\s*[a-z])
```

But it's not working. Any thoughts on how to do this?

It should capture `"red, white and blue"` but not `"red, white, and blue"`

Comment: Can you add some example strings and expected outputs?

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why you have an apostrophe at the end of your pattern. 
In `(\s*or|and+)`, you should move the `\s*` outside so as `and` could also be matched after a space, and `+` is totally redundant (as `anddd` will not likely be ever met). 
In `(\s*[a-z])`, the `+` quantifier is missing, and you will only match a single letter instead of a full word.

I assumed the matches should appear in some larger textual context, and I have tried to keep the capturing groups intact, too:

```
([a-z]+)((?:,\s*[a-z]+)*)\s+(and|or)\s+([a-z]+)
```

Have a look at the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/dJ2pY3/1) and [IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/YQGA6u).

Comment: The trailing apostrophe should have been removed along with the leading backtick when @BhargavRao added proper code formatting; I fixed it.  Also, I think the second `*` in `((?:,\s*[a-z]+)*)` should be a `+`.  If the goal is to add Oxford commas where they're missing, you don't want to match two-item "lists" like `black and blue` and `true or false`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this RegEx

```
\w+(?:,\s*\w+)*\s+(?:and|or)\s+\w+
```

[See demo.](https://regex101.com/r/uE3cC4/18#python)

Comment: Why are you anchoring the search to the start of the string?

Comment: Note that you get exactly the same effect if you leave out the `\b` :-) but it does no harm and adds clarity.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, but `\w+` will start (and stop) matching at a word boundary. It makes **no** difference.

Comment: @alexis yups removed `\b`